# how to encode a list of int in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I encode a list of int in flutter?

```
  static Future<void> setIdList(List<int> idList) async {
    var box = Hive.box(HIVE_DB_NAME);
    String jsonData = json.encode(
      List<int>.from(
        idList.map(
          (e) => e.toString(),
        ),
      ),
    );
    await box.put(ID_kEY, jsonData);
  }
```

As you can see I have already tried with `toString()` method but it gives me an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because you set your List of type `int` but you are actually creating a List of type `type` by calling the `toString` method. To fix thischange the type of your list to `String`.

```
 static Future<void> setIdList(List<int> idList) async {
    var box = Hive.box(HIVE_DB_NAME);
    String jsonData = json.encode(
      List<String>.from(
        idList.map(
          (e) => e.toString(),
        ),
      ),
    );
    await box.put(ID_kEY, jsonData);
  }
```